# If $\overline{L}$ is NL-hard, can we infer that $L$ is also NL-hard?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

**NL** denotes the class of languages, which can be decided by a non-deterministic Turing machine using $O(\log n)$ work tape cells.

A language $L$ is said to be **NL**-hard if $\forall L' \in$ **NL** : $L'\leq_L L\,$ (NL-hardness)

where $\leq_L$ denotes the log-space reduction, which is also transitive.

---

Given a language L. Is the following claim true?

*Claim*: If $\overline{L}$ is **NL**-hard, then $L$ also **NL**-hard.

Given that $\overline{L}$ is **NL**-hard, we can log-space-reduce every problem contained in **NL** to $\overline{L}$, i.e. $\forall L'\in$ **NL** : $L'\leq_L \overline{L}$. Due to the Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem we know that **coNL = NL**, but I do not know whether I can make progress with that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some language $L'\in \text{NL}$, so since $\text{NL=coNL}$ we have $\overline{L'}\in \text{NL}$, and since $\overline{L}$ is $\text{NL}$-hard we have $\overline{L'}\leq_{log}\overline{L}$  therefore $L'\leq_{log}L$ (with the same reduction)